# Installing the English (United States) language

Tags: 2.2-froyo, languages, htc-desire-hd

I recently got my Desire HD, and it came pre-installed with Deutsch, English, Spanish, French and Portuguese, each in a (Spain) or (Portugal) flavor. Is there some way of getting an English (United States) or English (United Kingdom) on it?
 Removing the other languages as well, would be nice.

Comment: I think "English" if not otherwise specified is "U.S. English"

Comment: Well' at the moment I have English (Spain)

Answer (score 3):

Android's language/locale/internationalization support is pretty bad at the moment.  I'd recommend flashing a US or UK ROM on it, which will have the language built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Download [MoreLocale2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale) from the Market, then you can change the UI language with a push of a button, without reboot.